# Get concatenated value from result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[shuffleChoices]
    @subjectID int, @personID int, @itemCount int
as
    SELECT TOP (@itemCount) question,
    answer = CONCAT('A. ',CA.[1]),
       distractor1 = CONCAT('B. ',CA.[2]),
       distractor2 = CONCAT('C. ',CA.[3]),
       distractor3 = CONCAT('D. ',CA.[4]),
       CONCAT(SUBSTRING(answer,0,2),trueanswer) AS trueanswer
FROM   user_items
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   (SELECT x,
                                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
                            FROM   (VALUES(answer),
                                          (distractor1),
                                          (distractor2),
                                          (distractor3)) V(x)) ps 
                            PIVOT (MAX(x) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) p) CA
WHERE subjectID = @subjectID and personID = @personID
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

What this does is it shuffles the values of columns **answer**, **distractor1**, **distractor2**, and **distractor3**

What I wanted to do was to get the letter of the correct answer. The values of columns **answer** and **trueanswer** are always the same without the shuffling inside the table. I tried to concatenate **answer** to **trueanswer** but the result I'm getting is this:

[image: Result]

It always get the first character of the value itself. How can I get the concatenated letters without updating the table?

Comment: change SUBSTRING(answer,0,2) to SUBSTRING(answer,0,0), if that's not your goal, then provide a sample of the final result that you're seeking.

Comment: If you only want to copy the letter of the answer use LEFT(answer, 1) this would get the first letter from the left side and leave the rest.

Comment: It still does not get the first letter. For example, for row 1 in the image above, the answer was in column **distractor2**, so, the value for column **trueanswer** must be **C.**. Applying SUBSTRING(answer,0,0) and LEFT(answer,1) still produce the same output

Comment: there is no need to use substring() and concat, you only need to use LEFT(answer, 1) + LEFT(trueanswer, 1) AS trueanswer this should do joining part with first letters, so in your example the return of it will be AC, then you can do the comparison.

Comment: @iSR5 it produces this: http://prntscr.com/i6ezdk it gets the actual value of  from the table not the concatenated one from the result

Comment: `substring` in sql server is 1 based, not 0 (like c# and many others).

Comment: LEFT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(answer,0,1), trueanswer ), 1) AS trueanswer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have a DataTable in C#.NET. What I did was compare the values of column **trueanswer** in the columns **answer**, **distractor1**, **distractor2**, and **distractor3**. After that, I just concatenated the corresponding letters, updated my DataTable then bind it to my reportviewer. Sorry for the confusion! :)